# Unable to get a secure connection to AWS DynamoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I keep getting the following errors trying to write to a table in my ios objective-c app:

> The request failed. Error: [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x12764c8f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

What is wrong above?

Comment: Show your code on how you are getting the secured connection?

Comment: It is all right over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108904/using-aws-developer-identities-for-authentication-for-ios-objective-c